# MS-Access Crosstab Query Sorting Column Headings

Tags: ms-access, pivot-table, columnheader

A query in MS-Access is creating a table, say tbl_WeekNums, which has exactly 2 fields and exactly 52 records. The values in field "YYYYWW" are sorted in descending order. The values in the other field are "calculated" values based on the values in field "YYYYWW".

[image]

The values of column "Week Num - Year" are used as the horizontal column headings (not the vertical row headings) in a CrossTab query. However, the column headings in the CrossTab query are getting "auto-sorted" as

[image]

Is there any way to get these column headings, in the CrossTab query, sorted like below?

[image]

Comment: Create the SQL of the query from code and specify the `IN` statement as described [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361).

Comment: Using IN clause means have to modify every year. This is text so alpha sort rules apply. I would use the YYYYMM field for Header row. If you must include "Week" and hyphen then calculate a format of YYYYMM to include but still have YYYY precede MM.

Comment: Correction: YYYYWW.